# Is this RPC communication?

Tags: ros, xmlrpc, master, rostopic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

i'm using ssh for ROS network communication.

i setted ROS_IP, ROS_MASTER_URI up IP Address that is working roscore.

i'm working roscore,  roslisp_reql in local.

and i'm working turtlesim_node in ssh.

Is this RPC communication??

if not, plz reply what kinds of network communication.

and To do RPC communication, plz reply to me how to do.  T.T

finally, Is master different from topic?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202804/is-this-rpc-communication???/) by [GodDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21596/goddong/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-10

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

It sounds like you've already found the [ROS Tutorials](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Tutorials)

The master and topic are very different. I suggest you read the [Concepts wiki page](http://wiki.ros.org/ROS/Concepts)

Some of the turtlesim elements are ROS services which are a style of RPC.

---

Originally posted by [tfoote](https://answers.ros.org/users/3/tfoote/) with karma: 58457 on 2015-02-11

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [GodDong](https://answers.ros.org/users/21596/goddong/) on 2015-02-11**:
first, Thank u for answer.
Is my question a part of RPC communication method??